# Win32: how does the OS decide to re-assign focus on window close?

Tags: windows, winapi, window-style

When a focused window is closed, Windows will typically set focus to a different window when possible. I'm trying to figure out what exactly causes this to happen, and in what scenarios does this not occur.

I'm noticing that when some windows are closed, they **do not** cause the OS to set focus to a new window (eg. Discord, Slack). Discord and Slack are both hidden instead of destroyed on close, but then there are also other windows that when *hidden* will still cause the OS to set focus to a different window. One such example is with a fresh WPF app and changing the window's [`Visibility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visibility?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to `Collapsed` - this causes the window to be hidden, not destroyed, and yet the OS reassigns focus to another window.

**What causes some windows when hidden to reassign focus (eg. WPF collapse)?** As opposed to applications like Discord/Slack, which are hidden, yet do not reassign OS focus.

Comment: General rule is there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#window-destruction "*If the window being destroyed is the active window, both the active and focus states are transferred to another window. The window that becomes the active window is the next window, as determined by the ALT+ESC key combination. The new active window then determines which window receives the keyboard focus*" I guess they mean ATL+TAB, not ALT+ESC (?) which list can be got with a code like this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071008-00/?p=24863

Comment: This is also important https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#keyboard-focus-and-activation and last, many apps try to hack the whole system https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/one-dev-minute/how-does-focus-management-work

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you, those resources were exactly what I was looking for. That explains why Discord/Slack does not cause focus to be re-assigned (since no destroy event is emitted). But one part I'm still unsure of is why some apps that *do not* emit a destroy event still cause focus re-assignment.

I can reproduce this by creating a fresh WPF app and setting the window's `Visibility` in the XAML to `Collapsed`. No destroy event is emitted, but Windows still reassigns focus. Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: I don't get your WPF "sample", behavior seems fully expected. Please add some reproducing code and explain what happens and what you'd expect.

Comment: @SimonMourier I don't disagree that it's expected behavior. Your first link mentioned "If the window being **destroyed** is the active window...", however, the WPF example is a case where the OS re-assigns focus even when *there is no destroy event*. This raises the question: under what circumstances does the OS reassign focus apart from window destroy events?

Comment: Like I said, I don't understand your WPF "example", what do you mean by destroy event? There's no destruction when you use WPFs collapse, the window is hidden, so it has no input, no focus and it out of the ALT+TAB list, so the focus goes on the next window in th ALT+TAB list.

Comment: @SimonMourier Windows can be destroyed via `DestroyWindow`, which will emit an [`EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/event-constants) event. The Microsoft article says that focus state is transferred when a window is destroyed. Like you said, the WPF window is hidden and not destroyed, so what I'm asking is what causes some windows when **hidden** to reassign focus (eg. WPF collapse), whereas others do not (eg. Slack, Discord)?

Comment: I know windows can be destroyed, but you're mixing many unclear questions here.

Comment: This question fits Raymond Chen's category of hard questions: "if you need to know then you're doing it wrong".  The most common doing-it-wrongs is displaying a dialog without an owner and displaying a window in a worker thread.  Get ahead by showing the code that triggered this question.

Comment: @HansPassant The use case is pretty niche: it's for a [Linux-like window manager but for Windows](https://github.com/lars-berger/GlazeWM). The WM takes over the native focus behavior and to do that, it needs to re-assign focus on window close after the OS sets focus

Comment: That's the job of the shell, any program that wants to behave like a shell needs to use SetWindowsHookEx() to install a WH_SHELL hook.  Not something you can do in WPF btw.  Notable how the question is remarkable unsuitable to elicit any useful responses that help you make a headstart on this.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not familiar with WH_SHELL hooks, but I'm afraid I don't see how one would help with overriding which windows gain focus on close/hide. My assumption would be that if the shell that is responsible for this, then wouldn't killing Explorer stop windows from gaining focus on close?

Comment: Several apps do this to try and increase engagement.

Comment: Check this one, I hope it will work for you. https://softans.com/question/win32-how-does-the-os-decide-to-re-assign-focus-on-window-close/#comments
@L.Berger

Answer (score 1):

It's a multi-step dance of message exchanges, and I no longer have all the details cached in my head.  So, generally speaking ...

There's a distinction between activating a window and setting the focus to a window.  Windows can get activated in various ways, including a mouse click (either in the client or non-client areas, a keyboard operation, a window being created by a process that currently has "the foreground love", etc.)

A window that's activated can (in effect) accept the focus, reject the focus, or direct the focus to another window (such as a child window like an edit control or button).

A window that doesn't make the effort to direct the focus explicitly when its activated will (likely) end up with the focus by default.  That's mostly an artifact of how DefWindowProc handles the relevant messages.  But if it's using the dialog manager, then the dialog manager will (if I recall correctly) set the focus to one of the child windows that has the WS_TABSTOP window style.

Imagine a simple text editor application that has a top-level window and one child window that fill the top-level window's client area and hosts the actual editor functionality.  In normal behavior, the child window would have the focus whenever the application is in the foreground.  But if the top-level window is activated (for something other than a mouse click in the child window's client area), and the top-level window fails to redirect the focus to its child, then it may appear as though nothing has the focus because the window that does have the focus doesn't respond to most kinds of keyboard input.

Key messages involved include:  WM_ACTIVATEAPP, WM_NCACTIVATE, WM_ACTIVATE, WM_MOUSEACTIVATE, WM_SETFOCUS, and WM_KILLFOCUS.

**Edited to emphasize**

> what causes the OS to re-assign focus from a window?

In most cases, the OS does not assign focus.  It activates and deactivates windows, and the affected applications respond to those events by setting the focus.  Applications have a lot of flexibility in how to respond.  So if there's an anomaly in where the focus is, it may be more of a question about the behavior of individual applications than about Windows.

It's also possible for a window to have focus but for it to seem as if no window has focus.  One case is where the top-level window has focus but doesn't react to the keyboard itself because focus is normally supposed to be assigned to one if its child windows.  It's also possible for a hidden window (at least a hidden child window) to have focus if it's not disabled.

Win32's DefWindowProc and dialog-specific APIs, MFC, WPF, and other frameworks generally provide "standard" behavior for handling focus and activation in common cases.  But there's a lot of nuance, and there are inherently some differences.  For example, WPF applications (if I recall correctly) use windowless child controls, so the traditional behaviors have to be implemented by the framework.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification regarding focus vs. activation, however, I don't think this adequately addresses the question

Comment: @L.Berger: You are correct.  Given how open-ended the question is and how complex this system is, I'm not sure the observed behavior can be answered without a much more specific scenario.  I started with a comment to try to provide information to enable deeper investigation of what appears to be going on, but it wasn't going to fit into a comment. I was also trying to point out that it may seem like no window has the focus when actually one might.

Comment: This doesn't answer what causes the OS to re-assign focus **from** a window (ie. what caused the OS to send the activation event in the first place?). As @SimonMourier answered, it is sent out when a window is destroyed, but there are some cases on window hide that the OS attempts to activate another window. But it's not 100% of all cases on window hide - Discord/Slack do cause activation, whereas WPF collapse does not. I'm trying to figure out why this is the case